# Get every 2 weeks on particular days SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query getting the days in particular day that I selected and show the days in a month. My problem is that I need every two weeks of the month. And I also need to get long date format: `dddd, dd MMMM yyyy` and eliminate the time. Please help me.

```
DECLARE @startDate DATETIME = '9/1/2019' 
DECLARE @endDate DATETIME = '12/31/2019' 
DECLARE @dayOfWeek INT = 1;

WITH cte_Recursion AS
(
    SELECT @startDate AS [Date]
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, [Date]) 
    FROM cte_Recursion 
    WHERE [Date] < @endDate
)
SELECT [Date] 
FROM cte_Recursion 
WHERE DATEPART(WEEKDAY, [Date]) = @dayOfWeek 
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

The data returned looks like this:

```
 2019-09-01 00:00:00.000
 2019-09-08 00:00:00.000
 2019-09-15 00:00:00.000
 2019-09-22 00:00:00.000
 2019-09-29 00:00:00.000
 2019-10-06 00:00:00.000
 2019-10-13 00:00:00.000
 2019-10-20 00:00:00.000
 2019-10-27 00:00:00.000
 2019-11-03 00:00:00.000
 2019-11-10 00:00:00.000
 2019-11-17 00:00:00.000
 2019-11-24 00:00:00.000
```

And I need to get like this (every other week):

```
 2019-09-01 00:00:00.000
 2019-09-15 00:00:00.000
 2019-09-29 00:00:00.000
 2019-10-13 00:00:00.000
 2019-10-27 00:00:00.000
 2019-11-10 00:00:00.000
 2019-11-24 00:00:00.000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By changing your CTE to start on the correct day of the week, you can then change the recursion to add 14 days instead of 1, giving you the desired result without further manipulation:

```
DECLARE @startDate DATETIME = '9/1/2019' 
DECLARE @endDate DATETIME = '12/31/2019' 
DECLARE @dayOfWeek INT = 1;
WITH cte_Recursion AS
  (SELECT DATEADD(DAY, ((@dayOfWeek - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @startDate)) % 7 + 7) %7, @startDate) AS [Date]
   UNION ALL SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 14, [Date]) 
   FROM cte_Recursion 
   WHERE DATEADD(DAY, 14, [Date])  < @endDate)
SELECT [Date] FROM cte_Recursion
```

Output:

```
Date
01/09/2019 00:00:00
15/09/2019 00:00:00
29/09/2019 00:00:00
13/10/2019 00:00:00
27/10/2019 00:00:00
10/11/2019 00:00:00
24/11/2019 00:00:00
08/12/2019 00:00:00
22/12/2019 00:00:00
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=9772517e5c2a6ca798284f06b6362a7c)

To change the date format to `dddd, dd MMMM yyyy`, simply replace the final `SELECT` with:

```
SELECT FORMAT([Date], 'dddd, dd MMMM yyyy') AS [Date] FROM cte_Recursion
```

Output:

```
Date
Sunday, 01 September 2019
Sunday, 15 September 2019
Sunday, 29 September 2019
Sunday, 13 October 2019
Sunday, 27 October 2019
Sunday, 10 November 2019
Sunday, 24 November 2019
Sunday, 08 December 2019
Sunday, 22 December 2019
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=ba0d5f0782d3f5ef064bf9d8663f0a4c)

Comment: But how do i eliminate the time?

Comment: I need to eliminate the time and set it as a longtime format like this dddd, dd MMMM yyyy

Comment: @kirbyhipona see my edit, that should give you the format you want

Comment: but got an error:  Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: The conversion does not match in datetime

Comment: What version of SQL server are you running?

Comment: I'm not sure why you should be seeing an error. My code is very close to your original code.

Answer (score 1):

you can use it :

```
 DECLARE @startDate DATETIME = '9/1/2019' 
   DECLARE @endDate DATETIME = '12/31/2019' 
   DECLARE @dayOfWeek INT = 1;
   WITH cte_Recursion AS
   (
   SELECT @startDate AS [Date]
   UNION ALL SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, [Date]) 
   FROM cte_Recursion WHERE [Date] < @endDate
   )
   SELECT [Date] FROM cte_Recursion 
   WHERE DATEPART(WEEKDAY, [Date]) = @dayOfWeek 
   and DATEPART(WEEK, [Date]) % 2 = 0
   OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Comment: I need to eliminate the time and set it as a longtime format like this dddd, dd MMMM yyyy

Comment: try it :  CONVERT(date, [Date])

Answer (score 1):

You could use a recursive CTE as

```
WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT  '2019-09-01 00:00:00.000' ADate
  UNION SELECT '2019-09-08 00:00:00.000'
  UNION SELECT '2019-09-15 00:00:00.000'
  UNION SELECT '2019-09-22 00:00:00.000'
  UNION SELECT '2019-09-29 00:00:00.000'
  UNION SELECT '2019-10-06 00:00:00.000'
  UNION SELECT '2019-10-13 00:00:00.000'
  UNION SELECT '2019-10-20 00:00:00.000'
  UNION SELECT '2019-10-27 00:00:00.000'
  UNION SELECT '2019-11-03 00:00:00.000'
  UNION SELECT '2019-11-10 00:00:00.000'
  UNION SELECT '2019-11-17 00:00:00.000'
  UNION SELECT '2019-11-24 00:00:00.000'
),
F AS
(
  SELECT CAST('2019-09-01 00:00:00.000' AS DATETIME) ADate
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATEADD(Day, 14, F.ADate)
  FROM F
  WHERE ADate < '2019-11-24 00:00:00.000'
)
SELECT *
FROM F;
```

Comment: And what if OP wants every Thursday instead?